# STM32 USART synchronous mode receive does not work

Tags: stm32, spi, uart, stm32l

I am using a STM32L052K6U6 to communicate with an SPI slave using the UART1 synchronous mode (configured with CubeMX, using the LL library).

Setup code generated by CubeMX (I left out the Tx and Clk pin config as those pins do what they should):

```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USART1_RX_ECG_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_MEDIUM;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_OPENDRAIN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_4;
  LL_GPIO_Init(USART1_RX_ECG_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  USART_InitStruct.BaudRate = 2000000;
  USART_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_USART_DATAWIDTH_8B;
  USART_InitStruct.StopBits = LL_USART_STOPBITS_0_5;
  USART_InitStruct.Parity = LL_USART_PARITY_NONE;
  USART_InitStruct.TransferDirection = LL_USART_DIRECTION_TX_RX;
  USART_InitStruct.OverSampling = LL_USART_OVERSAMPLING_8;

  LL_USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStruct);

  USART_ClockInitStruct.ClockPolarity = LL_USART_POLARITY_LOW;
  USART_ClockInitStruct.ClockPhase = LL_USART_PHASE_1EDGE;
  USART_ClockInitStruct.LastBitClockPulse = LL_USART_LASTCLKPULSE_OUTPUT;
  LL_USART_ClockInit(USART1, &USART_ClockInitStruct);

  LL_USART_EnableDEMode(USART1);

  LL_USART_DisableDEMode(USART1);

  LL_USART_DisableDMADeactOnRxErr(USART1);

  LL_USART_Enable(USART1);

  LL_USART_ConfigSyncMode(USART1);

  LL_USART_Enable(USART1);
```

Init code written by me, executed after the code above (the EnableDirection calls are not actually needed, Tx and RX is already enabled in the code above):

```
LL_USART_Disable(USART1);

LL_USART_SetTransferBitOrder(USART1, LL_USART_BITORDER_MSBFIRST);

LL_USART_EnableDirectionTx(USART1);
LL_USART_EnableDirectionRx(USART1);

LL_USART_Enable(USART1);
```

This is part of the code that receives data:

```
LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, 0);
while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(USART1));
while(LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(USART1));
uint8_t data_1 = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(USART1);
```

Probing the bus reveals that the clock generation and data sending works fine and the slave responds with the expected data. The receiver is enabled, but the data is not received by the microcontroller. The receive data register and the RXNE flag stay zero.
What could cause this?

Comment: Check the USART section of the reference manual.  It's not entirely clear if you are doing a one word transaction here or a write followed by a read, but I suspect what you want to watch is is the USART_ISR_TC flag in USART1->ISR

Comment: I am doing a one word transaction using the TransmitData function which writes to the USART1->TDR. The ReceiveData function just reads from USART1->RDR so it doesn't start a new transaction. Watching the TC flag instead of or in addition to the busy flag does not help.

Comment: You need to show your full code to reproduce the problem, especially the USART setup.  For all we can tell right now the receiver might not even be enabled.  As for the TC flag, was it seen immediately, or never?

Comment: I added the setup code to the question. I verified that the receiver is turned on using the register viewer in the debugger. The TC flag gets set at the end of the transmission, as expected.

Comment: Can you share your project please? I'm trying to do the similar project, but I can't understand how CubeMx generated USART1 initialisation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, but I don't know why it works.

There are some writes for initialization (max30003_init gets called once) and then repeated read sequences (max30003_readReg gets called regularly). 
The writing has always worked but receiving data (and the RXNE flag getting set) only works when disabling and then reenabling the USART after the initialization writes. Without it the program gets stuck waiting for RXNE to get set.
With this, the RXNE flag gets set as expected and the received data actually makes it to the receive data regster.

Complete code:

```
void max30003_init(void)
{
    LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);

    LL_USART_Disable(USART1);
    LL_USART_SetTransferBitOrder(USART1, LL_USART_BITORDER_MSBFIRST);
    LL_USART_Enable(USART1);

    LL_TIM_EnableCounter(TIM22);
    LL_TIM_CC_EnableChannel(TIM22, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH1); //32.7...kHz FCLK

    max30003_writeReg(REG_SW_RST,0x000000); //reset

    delay_ms(10);

    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_GEN, 0x081007);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_CAL, 0x720000);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_EMUX,0x0B0000);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_ECG, 0x805000);

    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_RTOR1,0x3fc600);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_SYNCH,0x000000);

    //FIXME: receive doesn't work without this!?
    LL_USART_Disable(USART1);
    LL_USART_Enable(USART1);

    delay_ms(10);
}

uint32_t max30003_readReg(uint8_t reg)
{
    while(LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(USART1));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(USART1));

    LL_USART_RequestRxDataFlush(USART1); //clear RXNE

    LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, ((reg << 1) | READ));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1));
    LL_USART_RequestRxDataFlush(USART1); //clear RXNE

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, 0);
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1));
    uint8_t data_2 = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(USART1);

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, 0);
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1));
    uint8_t data_1 = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(USART1);

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, 0);
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(USART1));
    uint8_t data_0 = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(USART1);

    LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);

    return ((data_2 << 16) | (data_1 << 8) | data_0);
}

void max30003_writeReg(uint8_t reg, uint32_t data)
{
    while(LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(USART1));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(USART1));

    LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, ((reg << 1) | WRITE));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(USART1));

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, (uint8_t)(data >> 16));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(USART1));

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, (uint8_t)(data >> 8));
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(USART1));

    LL_USART_TransmitData8(USART1, (uint8_t)data);
    while(!LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TC(USART1));

    LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);
}
```

I have no idea why the USART disable pulse is needed. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

This is caused by the the overrun error bit, disabling the overrun detection solves the problem. The reference manual explains it in a note: "When this bit is set, the RDR register content is not lost but the shift register is overwritten." No new RDR data also means the RXNE flag doesn't get set.
New init code:

```
void max30003_init(void)
{
    LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin(ECG_CS_GPIO_Port, ECG_CS_Pin);

    LL_USART_Disable(USART1);
    LL_USART_SetTransferBitOrder(USART1, LL_USART_BITORDER_MSBFIRST);
    LL_USART_DisableOverrunDetect(USART1);
    LL_USART_Enable(USART1);

    LL_TIM_EnableCounter(TIM22);
    LL_TIM_CC_EnableChannel(TIM22, LL_TIM_CHANNEL_CH1); //32.7...kHz FCLK

    max30003_writeReg(REG_SW_RST,0x000000); //reset

    delay_ms(10);

    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_GEN, 0x081007);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_CAL, 0x720000);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_EMUX,0x0B0000);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_ECG, 0x805000);

    max30003_writeReg(REG_CNFG_RTOR1,0x3fc600);
    max30003_writeReg(REG_SYNCH,0x000000);

    delay_ms(10);
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You're probably letting it get into a bad state, which resetting it is undoing.  Try reading out all of the status/flag/error registers before and after the reset.

Comment: It was indeed the overrun error bit, disabling the overrun detection solved the problem.

I ignored it until now as I thought it was only a status bit that has no influence on the functionality but the reference manual explains it in a note:

"When this bit is set, the RDR register content is not lost but the shift register is overwritten." No new RDR data also means the RXNE flag doesn't get set.

Comment: As a guess, you may get the overrun error by ignoring the read side when doing what you think of as writes.  The hardware doesn't have any real way to know that you don't care about what is being clocked in on MISO at that point.

Comment: You are correct, I already added the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Wait for `TXE` before transmitting
- Wait for `RXNE` instead of monitoring the `BUSY` bit before reading the answer. Waiting on `BUSY` that way might fail when an interrupt comes at the wrong time, and the data might not yet be transferred to the data register when `BUSY` goes to `0`.
- Check `CPOL` and `CPHA`, it might be sampling the input at the wrong time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  
Waiting for TXE did not help.  
Waiting for RXNE does not work, as the RXNE flag never gets set, so the program gets stuck there.  
CPOL and CPHA should be correct, as the transmitted data is clocked out on the correct edges. Also even when sampling at the wrong time, RXNE should get set at the end.